# How do I remove and/or change the speed of the minimize animation for application windows in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, catalina

When I click on the yellow minimize button at the top of an application window, it takes forever for the application to minimize and go into the dock. Is there a way to remove or change the speed of this animation?

I recently came across a terminal command that changes the speed of the dock animation `defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -int 0; defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 1.0; killall Dock` where `1.0` can be substituted for any non-negative number, so I assume there is a similar command for changing the speed of the minimize animation.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a speed setting for this action.

That said, the default setting for the **Dock** preference **Minimize windows using:** is **Genie effect** and the **Scale effect** may be a bit faster, so I'd try that one.

There is also a **Suck effect**, which can be implemented via **Terminal**, using the following *compound command*:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mineffect -string suck; killall Dock
```

Note that after using the above *compound command* you will not see **Suck effect** as a setting for **Minimize windows using:** as a **Dock** preference, however using the following *command* will show  the present *value*, e.g.:

```
% defaults read com.apple.dock mineffect
suck
%
```

Comment: FYI: it still works in macOS Ventura 13.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the Reduce Motion setting in the Accessibility section of preferences will speed things up a bit. Hope this helps!